# serialization on a wrapper class with a dictionary of nested class?

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary, deserialization

I have two classes that need to be serialized to a file. Here is the basic Item class.

```
[Serializable()]
public class Item:ISerializable,...
{
    ......
    private string _itemName;

    [NonSerialized]
    private Inventory _myInventory;

    private double _weight;
    ....

    event PropertyChangingEventHandler propertyChanging;
    event PropertyChangingEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanging.PropertyChanging
    {
        add { propertyChanging += value;}
        remove { propertyChanging -= value; }
    }

    public string Name {get;set;....}
    public double Weight {get;set;...}
    ....

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Name", _itemName);
        info.AddValue("Weight", _weight);

        Type t = this.GetType();
        info.AddValue("TypeObj", t);
    }

    internal Item(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
    {
        _itemName = info.GetString("Name");
        _weight = info.GetDouble("Weight");
    }
```

And here is the Inventory class:

```
   [Serializable()]
   public class Inventory:......
   {
       private int _numOfProduct = 0;
       private int _numOfItems = 0;

       private Dictionary<string, Item> _inventoryDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
       .....

       public IEnumerable<Item> GetSortedProductsByName()
       {
        return _inventoryDictionary.OrderBy(key => key.Key).Select(key => key.Value).ToList();
       }

       .....
   }
```

When I tested the binary serialization to files with:

```
   //serialize 
   ....
   fs = File.OpenWrite(FileName);  //FileName = "C:/temp/foo.bin"
   b.Serialize(fs, products); 
   fs.Close(); 

   ....
   //deserialize 
   Inventory products = new Inventory();
   BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
   fs = File.OpenRead(FileName);
   products = (Inventory)b.Deserialize(fs);
   ...
```

When I tested the serialization it appears that the following code doesn't work as expected:
      ....
      foreach (var item in products.GetSortedProductsByName())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                            }
      ....

I debugged through the lines and found that item is always null although product is not null.

Any thoughts?

If anyone knows somewhere that I can find a similar sample implementation of my scenario, please let me know.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You're going to have to include the _full_ code that reproduces the problem. I don't see any problems with that code and what you show here doesn't produce the problem you describe when run.